# JComponent painting issue

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, jcalendar

I'm trying to create a custom Calendar in Java. For this I extend `javax.swing.JComponent`.

```
public class GMCalendar extends JComponent { ... }
```

In my constructor I do some basic setup and load my image:

```
calendarDay = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/calendar_day.png"));
```

And in `paintComponent` it should draw my calendar, but it won't draw all, which looks very weird.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
    int numberOfWeeks = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfWeeks; j++) {
            int x = i * (DAY_SIZE + DAY_SPACE);
            int y = j * (DAY_SIZE + DAY_SPACE);
            g.drawImage(calendarDay, x, y, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is either nothing or something like this:

[image: Weird calendar]

It seems like `paintComponent` gets called **before** the component has a size bigger than *1x1*.

This is in my `main()`:

```
GMContainerFrame cf = new GMContainerFrame();
cf.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800,600));
cf.setVisible(true);
```

This is from the constructor of `GMContainerFrame` (which doesn't use a `LayoutManager`!):

```
calendarFrame = new GMMiniFrame("Kalender", new GMCalendar(), 230);
```

`GMMiniFrame` extends `JSplitPane`.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner, but as said by @mKobel (+1 to his answer) have a look at 3rd party library unless you yourself are creating a calendar library. Also dont call `setPreferredSize` rather override `getPreferredSize()`

Comment: Should I say something else -- You shouldn't write `calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);` in `paintComponent()` because `paintComponent()` will be invoked by the system when it repaints. You are adding all the time which is not good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- don't to reinvent the wheel, use `JPanels`, better with `JLabels` layed by `GridLayout`
- by using `JLabels` (`JPanel` nesting multiple `JComponents`) there no reason for `paintComponents`
- notice `JLabel` is transparent, non_opaque,
- use `JCalendar`/`JDatePicker` from `SwingX`, my favorite is [JCalendar by Kai Toedter](http://www.toedter.com/), (no issue with renderer, editor, special days, min and max Date)

Comment: +1, especially for first & last comment.  People don't realize how hard it is to make a robust calendar component.

Comment: Also see http://jdatepicker.org which is an alternative to the components mentioned above.